# RobotFramework : How to get information using 'following-sibling'

Tags: xpath, robotframework

I want to recover the value of the account status "RF-Account" as shown in the picture.
[image] For this, I target an xpath to retrieve the value just to the right of it with this code in RobotFramework :
`${initialStatus}=    Get Value    //td[text()='${testAccount}']/following-sibling::span[@style=""]`

Here is the html code of the information to retrieve:
`<span class="text-bold ng-binding text-green" ng-class="{'text-green' : tenant.status == 'ACTIVE', 'text-muted' : tenant.status == 'INACTIVE'}" style="">ACTIVE</span>`

And the html snippet that contains whole table :

```
<tbody ng-if="!isEmpty" class="body-table ng-scope" style="height: 193px;">
        <!-- ngRepeat: tenant in tenants track by $index --><tr ng-repeat="tenant in tenants track by $index" class="ng-scope" style="">
            <td class="ng-binding">RF-Accoun</td>
            <td>
                <span class="text-bold ng-binding text-green" ng-class="{'text-green' : tenant.status == 'ACTIVE', 'text-muted' : tenant.status == 'INACTIVE'}">ACTIVE</span>
            </td>
            <td style="width:118px">
                <div class="pull-right">
                    <a name="editBtn" type="submit" class="btn-icon" ng-click="openCreateEditModal(tenant)">
                        <span class="icon-i-edit fs"></span>
                    </a>
                    <a name="deleteBtn" type="submit" class="btn-icon" ng-click="deleteTenant(tenant)">
                        <span class="icon-i-trash fs"></span>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr><!-- end ngRepeat: tenant in tenants track by $index --><tr ng-repeat="tenant in tenants track by $index" class="ng-scope">
            <td class="ng-binding">RF-Account</td>
            <td>
                <span class="text-bold ng-binding text-green" ng-class="{'text-green' : tenant.status == 'ACTIVE', 'text-muted' : tenant.status == 'INACTIVE'}">ACTIVE</span>
            </td>
            <td style="width:118px">
                <div class="pull-right">
                    <a name="editBtn" type="submit" class="btn-icon" ng-click="openCreateEditModal(tenant)">
                        <span class="icon-i-edit fs"></span>
                    </a>
                    <a name="deleteBtn" type="submit" class="btn-icon" ng-click="deleteTenant(tenant)">
                        <span class="icon-i-trash fs"></span>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr><!-- end ngRepeat: tenant in tenants track by $index --><tr ng-repeat="tenant in tenants track by $index" class="ng-scope">
            <td class="ng-binding">RF-Account-bis</td>
            <td>
                <span class="text-bold ng-binding text-green" ng-class="{'text-green' : tenant.status == 'ACTIVE', 'text-muted' : tenant.status == 'INACTIVE'}">ACTIVE</span>
            </td>
            <td style="width:118px">
                <div class="pull-right">
                    <a name="editBtn" type="submit" class="btn-icon" ng-click="openCreateEditModal(tenant)">
                        <span class="icon-i-edit fs"></span>
                    </a>
                    <a name="deleteBtn" type="submit" class="btn-icon" ng-click="deleteTenant(tenant)">
                        <span class="icon-i-trash fs"></span>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr><!-- end ngRepeat: tenant in tenants track by $index -->
    </tbody>
```

It doesn't work. Could you, please, correct me for it to work ?

Comment: Could you provide html snippet that contains whole table?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what it means when you say: "doesn't work". Is there an error, you get a different element. Have you tried using an xPath plugin for your browser to see what the xpath results to? In my view it's not Robot Framework, but purely an xPath issue.

Comment: Indeed, it's indeed a syntax error on the xPath. I use this one in Robot Framework. I need some help to write the xPath correctly which will allow me to get the value just right following the name of the account

Answer (score 1):

First, you should use keyword `Get Text`, because `Get Value` return `value` attribute of element. In your case your element do not have this attribute, so I assume that you want text.

Second, `span` elements from html snippet containing whole table differ from `span` element that your provided separately. They do not contain `style` attribute.

Finally the most probable solution to your problem is:

```
Get Text    //td[text()='${testAccount}']/following-sibling::td/span
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanations. It's clearer for my mind. that's exactly what I was trying to solve